# Why $\dim(R/\mathrm{Jac}(R))=0$ for Dedekind domain $R$ with $\mathrm{Jac}(R)\neq 0$?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, krull-dimension, dedekind-domain

Let $R$ be a Dedekind domain and its Jacobson radical is non-zero $\mathrm{Jac}(R)\neq 0$. Why $\dim(R/\mathrm{Jac}(R))=0$?

Comment: For any Noetherian domain $R$ with $\dim R=n$ and $=\neq a\in R$, $\dim R/aR<n$. Dedekind domains are Noetherian of dimension one.

Comment: Note that such a ring is necessarily semilocal.

Answer (score 2):

Since  Dedekind domains are one dimensional, every non zero prime ideal is maximal. If $Jac(R)\not=0$, then every prime ideal of $    R/Jac (R) $ must be maximal. Thus, $R/Jac (R) $ is zero dimensional.

Comment: Thank you. Why Dedekind domains are one dimensional?